# SMTP in ASP.NET application - mails are being rejected

Tags: c#, email, dns, smtp

My IIS is running an ASP.NET web application. I use a local smtp server to send emails. I just installed smtp service and use the following config section:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp from="support@mydomain.de" deliveryMethod="Network">
            <network host="localhost" />
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

The web server is not running the default mailserver for this domain (MX record is different).

Now I have the following problem. My outgoing mails are being rejected by some mail servers. Last week I discovered my mails are being rejected by all Microsoft servers (hotmail.de / hotmail.com / outlook.com domains)

```
Final-Recipient: rfc822;mailaddress@outlook.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.5.0
Diagnostic-Code: smtp;550 SC-001 (SNT004-MC1F46) Unfortunately, messages from xx.xx.xx.xx weren't sent. Please contact your Internet service provider since part of their network is on our block list. You can also refer your provider to http://mail.live.com/mail/troubleshooting.aspx#errors.
```

(receipient mailaddress is replaced by mailaddress@outlook.com and my server's ip by xx.xx.xx.xx for security reasons)

So I tried to add a SPF text record to my dns configuration for my domain.

```
v=spf1 mx ip4:xx.xx.xx.xx a:mydomain.de -all
```

with no effect. The mails are still rejected.

Today I discovered in addition all the mails to United Internet servers (web.de, gmx.de, gmx.net) are also rejected.

```
Final-Recipient: rfc822;mailaddress@gmx.de
Action: failed
Status: 4.4.7
```

According a [post on serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/295409/how-to-solve-error-550-4-4-7) this is the same problem but different error code due to different server behavior.

So my question: what is the correct configuration to send emails via local smtp (which is not the domain smtp according to mx records) without being rejected -what changes are to be made?

Answer (score 0):

The first block is a permanent block from microsoft you must fill up this form for remove the block (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/getsupport?oaspworkflow=start_1.0.0.0&wfname=capsub&productkey=edfsmsbl3&locale=en-us)

if you have a dedicated ip you can register the SNDS program of microsoft to monitoring your ip.

A smtp error starts with 4 is a temporary error maybee your mailserver is not configured perfect. You can check your configuration with send a test mail to this audit tool (https://emailaudit.com)